# Difference between refresh and incremental refresh

Tags: tableau-api

what is the actual difference between refresh and the incremental load(with some full refresh) with extract

when does only inserts will occur and when does both inserts and updates will occur

which is really helpful for the incremental load

Answer (score 0):

According to http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/optimizing-incremental-refreshes

> (...) you can configure Tableau to incrementally refresh your extract by taking only rows that are new to the underlying data since the previous refresh was performed, and adding it to your extract.

When you define a incremental update you can define the columns that should be used to identify new records (ie. define the unique key to check if the record is already in the extract or if it needs to be added). This results in faster refresh times but at the same time you have to be aware that changes to existing rows will not be reflected unless you do a full refresh.

In case you have a big data set, that is something you might want to do outside office hours while at the same time give your employees access to the latest data during the day with an incremental refresh.

Answer (score 0):

We use a simple litmus test when establishing incremental or full refresh conditions to our extract files.  If the data source is "Inset Only" then an incremental refresh is fine as the data doesn't change, so performing a full refresh won't provide any direct value.

Anytime there are updates made to previously extracted data, Tableau won't recognize these changes unless you produce a full refresh.  A full refresh will be more resource intensive - but more accurately presents historical data.  We looked for a way to perform a rolling refresh - where the data would refresh values only just updated over the past 2 years - which would act like a in between but couldn't find a way to make it work.

If you are concerned with load - you can perform an incremental refresh during the week to keep the load to a minimum and then do a full refresh only once a week.  We have adopted this strategy for a while and it has been working thus far.